# get input values inside a table td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have table with a button as following; I'm trying to get the values of td's using jQuery.

My table:

```
<table class="table" id="Tablesample">

    <tr>
        <th style="display:none;">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
        </th>

    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td style="display:none;" class="keyvalue">
                <input type="text" name="Key" value="@item.Key" class="form-control" id="configKey" readonly="readonly">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="Key" value="@item.Id" class="form-control" id="configId" readonly="readonly">
            </td>
        </tr>

    }

</table>

<button id="btnSave">Save</button>
```

then I'm trying to get the value using jquery:

```
$('#btnSave').click(function () {

    $('#Tablesample tr').each(function () {

        var row = $(this).closest("tr");    // Find the row
        var text = row.find(".keyvalue").text(); // Find the text
        var keval = text.find("input").text();

        alert(keval);
    });

});
```

but I'm not getting any values.

I also tried something like this but it doesn't work either:

```
$("#Tablesample tr:gt(0)").each(function () {

    var this_row = $(this);
    var key = $.trim(this_row.find('td:eq(0)').html());
    alert(key);
});
```

Comment: Please click the `<>` button and create a [mcve] - for sure `text.find("input").text();` is not valid jQuery - text is a string and .keyvalue is a cell with an input. Perhaps you mean to get the value of the field? that would be $(fieldSelector).val() - also you do not have unique IDs

Comment: nope that not a issue

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is due to your DOM traversal logic. Firstly `this` is the `tr` element, so `closest('tr')` won't find anything. Secondly, you're getting the string value from the `text()` of `.keyvalue`, then attempting to find an `input` element in the text instead of traversing the DOM. Finally, you need to use `val()` to get the value of an input.

I'd strongly suggest you familiarise yourself with the methods jQuery exposes and how they work: http://api.jquery.com

With all that said, this should work for you:

```js
$('#btnSave').click(function() {
  $('#Tablesample tr').each(function() {
    var keval = $(this).find(".keyvalue input").val();
    console.log(keval);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="Tablesample">
  <tr>
    <th style="display:none;">
      Model
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="display:none;" class="keyvalue">
      <input type="text" name="Key" value="Key1" class="form-control" id="configKey" readonly="readonly">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="Key" value="Id1" class="form-control" id="configId" readonly="readonly">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="display:none;" class="keyvalue">
      <input type="text" name="Key" value="Key2" class="form-control" id="configKey" readonly="readonly">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="Key" value="Id2" class="form-control" id="configId" readonly="readonly">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="display:none;" class="keyvalue">
      <input type="text" name="Key" value="Key3" class="form-control" id="configKey" readonly="readonly">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="Key" value="Id3" class="form-control" id="configId" readonly="readonly">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="btnSave">Save</button>
```

Note that the first value is `undefined` as your `th` element in the first row contains no `input` element. I'd suggest separating the table using `thead`/`tbody` if you want to exclude that row.

Comment: wht happen if i have multiple `input` inside single <td>

Comment: Then you would need to select the `input` you require specifically - by `id` or `class` for example

Comment: `var keval = $(this).find(".keyvalue .your-input-class-here").val();`

Comment: I put like this to avoid undefined thing but         `<table>
  <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                       
                    </th>        
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
    <tr>
                         <td>                            
                        </td>        
                </tr>

                }
            </tbody>
        </table>` its still there

Comment: In that case change `$('#Tablesample tr')` to `$('#Tablesample tbody tr')`. I'd suggest you research how selectors work too. For reference it's the same pattern that CSS uses

Comment: thnks lot its helps

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan- Instead of traversing thru' all the `tr`s of a table, how can we get the value from a `td` using its ID?  If I use `$('#Tablesample tr').each(function() {...});` it runs thru' the entire gamut of rows and on finding the right ID, spits out the value (correctly). Instead of that, can I get the value straight off the cell's ID?

Comment: Of course. Just use a standard id selector as you would on any other element in jQuery

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - I have over a thoiusand rows in a table with some of the cells (inputs) blank. How do I approach picking out those elements? Is it really possible to only hit those **empty** cells  without looping thru' each of the rows?

Comment: It's impossible to tell the exact context of the problem without seeing the code. I'd suggest starting a new question. However I would suggest that having over 1000 rows in a page is a little too much. You should perhaps look in to a paging and filtering system